# Android storage problem

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory

With a phone of 1 GB internal memory, I am able to install apps for 700 MB only. More than that I get the insufficient memory alert.

Storage shows:

```
Total space 0.98

Available 71.49
Apps 601
Cache 1.88
```

Another phone of the same model is able to able to install apps for the entire 1GB.

Phone runs on Android version 4.2.x. Default write disk is external SD card.

Thanks in advance. Screenshots below:

[image: my-phone] [image: other-phone]
<sup>Screenshots: My phone, other phone (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Comment: What's your question? And what phone do you have?

Comment: @DanHulme why am I able to install apps for 700 MB only and not one GB. It is a Micromax A116 HD.

Answer (score 1):

In most android devices this insufficient storage issue is to do with Log files being dumped in the `/data/log` folder. The log files appear to be the logdump for the gsm radio, and can take up a lot of space over time (Gigabytes even).

Most phones without root have a workaround to delete the logs by dialing `*#9900#` from the phones dial pad. If your phone supports this then the moment you finish entering the 2nd hash, a menu will open up (point is: if it doesnt support nothing happens; pressing the call button wont help). In the menu that opens, select "delete dumpstate/logcat". That will free up all the space occupied by those logs.

Do let me know if any of you with a A116 is lucky to have this workaround. I have an A116 with the same problem, and am not able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The remaining storage is used for the Operating System(Android) itself.
 You can't free this space and put the operating system into the external card as it will not be possible to boot/switch on the phone.
The Micromax A116 comes with a 4 GB internal storage in which 1 GB is partitioned for Android apps including the operating system.
 The remaining storage is for user use and you can store data by opening the File Manager.
Source: I'm a Micromax A110 user and an app developer.

Comment: But my friend is using the same phone and his available space shows 1 go.

Comment: There are 2 possibilities: 1st that his phone might be rooted and he might have extended it. 2nd you might have seen the internal storage. Internal SD card. Internal sd card is different than internal storage. Please post a screenshot of settings>storage

Comment: His phone is not rooted. I want to post a screenshot but right now I am on the app. I will post the screenshot when I go online using a PC.

Comment: please take a look at the screenshots, you will understand the difference.

Comment: @soconfusing It also depends on the specific apps installed. Some apps have a greater chance of using and needing additional storage when being used; a reservation of space is needed to ensure proper performance.

Comment: "The remaining storage is used for the Operating System(Android) itself." – Nope. That resides in its own partition (`/system`), while "internal storage" rather refers to `/data` (basically), where apps are installed and store their data. In the screenshots, "My phone" reports ~55MB free on `/data`, which is pretty close to the safety margin (if `/data` runs out of space, the system freezes). This must be something different, numbers just don't match (used+free≠total) – which points to [invincis being right](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/89509/16575), as logs are not accounted for here.